# Getting Password can't be blank with has_secure_password

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Getting Password can't be blank while using has_secure_password feature in Rails 4.x:

Here are my files:

Gemfile has & I did the bundle install:

gem 'bcrypt'

This is the table

```
   create_table :teachers do |t|

   t.string :firstname, null: false
   t.string :lastname, null: false
   t.string :email, null: false
   t.string :cellphone
   t.string :username, null: false
   t.string :password_digest, null: false
   t.string :addr_streetno
   t.integer :addr_aptno
   t.string :addr_city
   t.string :addr_state
   t.integer :addr_zip
   t.binary :photo, :limit => 0.5.megabyte

   t.timestamps
end
```

This is the model file:

```
 class Teacher < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_many :students

    has_secure_password
    attr_accessor :password, :password_confirmation
    validates_presence_of :password, :on => :create

    EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\z/i
    validates :username, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true, :length => { :in => 3..20 }
    validates :email, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true, :format => EMAIL_REGEX
end
```

This is code for password fields in the form:

```
<tr>
   <th>Password</th>
   <td><%= f.password_field :password %></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <th>Confirm Password</th>
   <td><%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
```

This is the controller code:

```
class TeacherController < ApplicationController
  def index
      @teachers= Teacher.all 
  end

  def new
      @teacher = Teacher.new
  end

  def create
      @teacher = Teacher.new(teacher_params)
      if @teacher.save
        redirect_to :action => 'index'
      else
        render :action => 'new'
      end
  end

  def edit
  end

  def show
  end

private

    def teacher_params
      params.require(:teacher).permit(:firstname, 
                                      :lastname, 
                                      :dob, 
                                      :email, 
                                      :cellphone, 
                                      :username, 
                                      :password,
                                      :password_confirmation,
                                      :addr_streetno, 
                                      :addr_aptno, 
                                      :addr_city, 
                                      :addr_state,
                                      :addr_zip, 
                                      :photo)
    end
end
```

Comment: It would be easier to use [has_secure_password](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/SecurePassword/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_secure_password), it does the same thing.

Comment: Please share your controller code; do you have strong params defined which include `:password`?

Comment: The error is because the value for a password is less than 6 characters.Make sure the length is greater than or equal to 6

Comment: @Pavan You can't say that for sure. If strong parameters are used and `password` is not permitted, then the same error will be raised.

Comment: No, I was putting 'welcome' as the password. its 7 chars.

Comment: @GraemeMcLean I added the controller code. I have strong params but it does not have :password.

Comment: @GergoErdosi Can you give me an example of use_secure_password implementation

Comment: @gvermag You can find an example in the documentation I linked. All you need to add to your model is `has_secure_password`. You can then remove `encrypt_password`, `clear_password`, etc.

Answer (score 4):

```
attr_accessor :password, :password_confirmation
```

comment this line in Teacher class.

Answer (score 1):

In the model you have this line, which defines the length of your password. Change it to your requirements:

```
validates_length_of :password, :in => 6..20, :on => :create
```

Comment: Crispy, I was putting welcome as the password, so that should fall within the limits defined.

Answer (score 1):

In your controller `encrypted_password` is permitted:

```
params.require(:teacher).permit(:encrypted_password)
```

However it shouldn't be permitted, because users should not be able to change the value of `encrypted_password`. Remove `encrypted_password` from the list and add `password` and `password_confirmation`:

```
params.require(:teacher).permit(:password, :password_confirmation)
```

Comment: so I would take out before_save:, after_save:, and encrypt_password and clear_password from the model, after adding has_secure_password. Thats part of the problem. What are the other problems that I have.

Comment: When I added has_secure_password and removed the above mentioned things, it gives me an error on bcrypt. cannot load such file -- bcrypt. I verified that I have bcrypt 3.1.7 gem installed.

Comment: It's hard to explain in a comment how to use `has_secure_password`. If you have difficulties implementing it, I suggest to create a new question.

Comment: I went through http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/SecurePassword/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_secure_password, It seems intuitive. So I would need an attribute called password_digest. Would I need to put this in the migration file.

Comment: Yes, if you already use `encrypted_password`, you will need to rename it to `password_digest`. For the bcrypt issue, you can try changing the line `gem 'bcrypt'` to `gem 'bcrypt', require: 'bcrypt'` in Gemfile.

Comment: Did you restart the server after you added the bcrypt gem?

Comment: Crispy, restarting the rails server did the trick about the missing bcrypt gem. Now I am proceeding to fix the setup for the has_secure_password

Comment: @GergoErdosi I updated the issue description with the latest issue. the bcrypt not found issue was resolved by restarting the rails server . Now I am getting password cannot be blank. Is this due to the attr_accessor :password, :password_confirmation .. does it need to be attr_accessible: instead

Comment: @gvermag Remove `attr_accessor :password, :password_confirmation` and `validates_presence_of :password, :on => :create`. These are automatically added by `has_secure_password`.

Comment: @GergoErdosi You were right! This is most confusing. Why are there examples out in the web with that kind of code if its not needed in the first place. I was looking at http://www.millwoodonline.co.uk/blog/using-hassecurepassword-for-rails-authentication. Rails code is probably moving too fast.

Comment: @gvermag Good question, don't know why the author of that blog post added presence validation to `password`. That code might be outdated indeed.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the "Password can't be blank" validation error message, using Rails 4 and `has_secure_password`.

My model looked like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :email, presence: true, uniqueness: true
  has_secure_password
end
```

Strangely, moving the `validates` line to below the `has_secure_password` line fixed this. This worked:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_secure_password
  validates :email, presence: true, uniqueness: true
end
```

I thought I'd share, even though this question is old as it's the top result when searching for this issue, and all the other q&a's don't mention this.

Comment: Same for me. I needed just move `validates :email` upper than `devise ...` statement in my User model.